# Elasticsearch: Access values from buckets in aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I would like to create word clouds to visualize the results of Elasticsearch queries. In the word cloud all terms that occur in the documents that match the query should be displayed. So, I need to calculate the term frequencies for all terms that occur in some arbitrary set of documents. The problem is that I need the actual frequencies of all terms in the documents, and not just the number of documents a term occurs in (this is easily solved using a terms aggregation or facets).

Given the following test index

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "testdoc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "text" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "term_vector": "yes"
                }
            }
         }
    }
}'
```

and data:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/sports/_bulk" -d'
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"testdoc"}}
{"text":"bike bike car"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"testdoc"}}
{"text":"car"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"testdoc"}}
{"text":"car car bus bus"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"testdoc"}}
{"text":"bike car bus"}
'
```

The following query returns the term frequency of the term 'bike'.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/testdoc/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "words": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "text"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "tf_sum": {
                     "sum": {
                         "script": "_index[\"text\"][\"bike\"].tf()"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Result:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "words": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "car",
               "doc_count": 4,
               "tf_sum": {
                  "value": 3
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "bike",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "tf_sum": {
                  "value": 3
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "bus",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "tf_sum": {
                  "value": 1
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

However, instead of calculating the tf_sum for 'bike' only, I'd like to calculate the tf_sum for all terms returned by the words-aggregation. Is there a way to access the key field of the buckets in the script of the tf_sum aggregation, so I can calculate the total term frequency for all terms returned by the words-aggregation?

Comment: Did you consider using significant terms?

Answer (score 0):

Well we can achieve this by using script in terms aggregation. We can access the term value using the _value variable

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/testdoc/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "words": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "text",
                "script" : "_index[\"text\"][_value].tf()"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: this does not work in el 1.7.0, 
i got:    `"aggregations": {
      "words": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "0",
               "doc_count": 4
            }
         ]
      }
   }`